# why all the sudden I cannot access a remote SVN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, svn

I am working for a company remotely. The **SVN server** is running on their site. I access it from my home remotely for several months.

Yesterday morning I found I cannot access the SVN server. They were using port **540** before and they found that port is not available anymore. But don't know why. I can ping them without problem. Their SVN server is working internally within their local network.

Then they changed the port to **5400**. It allow access from outside now but not me. I asked my friends to access that port which also has a webpage, they all can see that webpage but I cannot. I always get timeout.

I have restarted my entire home network many times. My home network is consist of  a SB6120 SURFboard DOCSIS 3.0 **Cable Modem**, a NETGEAR ProSafe VPN Firewall **FVS318 router** and a TRENDnet **TEW-452BRP wireless router**.

I have **two machines**, a win7 and a Linux. Both are the same result. Most of time I am using **wireless** but I tried the wired **cable connection**. No difference.

There is no other abnormal networking activities found.

How can I find where is the issue?

I think the issue is on my side because my friends from CA and NH can access that site.

**EDIT:**

Now I am in the public library. I can access that site now from here.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a firewall issue somewhere. Possibly because [5400 has been](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewIpsSignature.x?signatureId=9216&signatureSubId=0&soft_2) associated with [trojans](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=5400) previously.

Check your router firewall for exclusions. Try manually adding an exception for 5400.

As a last-ditch attempt you could also try putting your linux machine address as a DMZ in the router (forward all traffic) just for a temporary test. I'd not advice this.

Comment: 5400 port is on their site, exclude it on my side?

Comment: Yes, you can whitelist it on your side. It's on your side that the firewall issue seems to be (as you say, because you can access from another remote location). For your router the default configuration page is http://192.168.0.1. If this does not bring you a webpage run `ipconfig` in `cmd` and use the value printed next to "default gateway".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to RJFalconer advice I'd recommend using tcpdump

```
tcpdump host your_svn_repository_IP -w filedump
```

This way you catch all traffic to and from your remote resource. Then you can load the file **filedump** to Wireshark with graphical interface to analize the content of all Ethernet frames.