# home network, routing table entries

Tags: networking, routing

In my home network, the router has the following entries in its routing table:

```
Destination     Mask             Gateway      Metric    Active
192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.0.1     1         Yes
146.115.72.0   255.255.252.0    146.115.74.4    1         Yes
```

I found the **146.115.74.4** is my ip, but I don't know where is the **146.115.72.0**. Does the second entry say all incoming traffic will be redirect to **146.115.72.0**?

And I cannot remember I have added anything or that entry here. it is added by the internet provider? or by the system itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**146.115.72.0** is you network IP. According to the mask **255.255.252.0**, CIDR network specification is **146.115.72.0/26**, so external IP address **146.115.74.4** is within the range of possible addresses **146.115.72.1 - 146.115.75.254**

These are quite typical settings no matter who set them up.

Comment: any advice on my this question: http://superuser.com/questions/1068555/why-all-the-sudden-i-cannot-access-a-remote-svn